# Create public key Certificate from public key only

Tags: .net, openssl, certificate, public-key-encryption

As I understand Certificates are signed public key of a user by CA.

I don't have CSR from user, I only have his public Key, and I want to certify it.

How can i certify this public key with OpenSSL (command line) or .net (with C# programming)?

EDIT: To be more exact I need to sign users public key, with CA private key, then build X509 text file and convert it somehow to .PEM or .DER file

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that the certificate is correctly signed with openssl but it depends on the format of the certificate.  If I "assume" the certificate is in [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) format.
e.g.

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text
```

will dump information stored in the certificate.  If anythning is incorrect it will "error" out.

You can check if the certificate is expired with:
openssl x509 -enddate -checkend 0 -noout -in cert.pem
This will display the end date (in utc) and if the certificate has expired.

You can also check that the certificate "chain" is correct using the [verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-verify.html) openssl command.
e.g.

```
openssl verify cert.pem
```

although you may need to include intermediate certificates and a calist if required.
e.g. This is an example of veriying a GoDady signed certificate chain:

```
openssl verify -CAfile .\gdroot-g2.crt -untrusted .\gdig2.crt.pem -show_chain .\server.pem
.\server.pem: OK
Chain:
depth=0: OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.XXXX.XXX (untrusted)
depth=1: C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2 (untrusted)
depth=2: C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
```

Most of this is done for you when you establish a [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) connection.

As for trying to do all this is code (e.g. C#) you will have to be a lot more specific about what you want to do.  If you just want to know if C# can "load" a certificate, you can use the [X509Certificate2Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection?view=netframework-4.7.2) [Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.import?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2Collection_Import_System_String_) method to import a PFX formatted certificate chain.

Once imported you can pull out any attributes you wish to look at.

You can verify the chain using the [X509Certificate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netframework-4.7.2) [Verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?view=netframework-4.7.2) mathod.

Comment: I need opposite of this. In other words i need openssl command to convert X509 ANS.1 plain text file (which i will write programmatically) to DER or PEM file.

Comment: DER is a ANS1 written to file (binary).  PEM is basically a base64 version of the ASN1 binary data with markup.  So I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: If it truely is a ANS.1 binrary file: "openssl x509 -in cert.pem -inform der -noout -text" should dump the file.  You do know ANS.1 is a encoding standard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) - x509 is the certificate standard that uses ANS.1.  So long as it's a x509 certificate then it should work.